# Link hover css not working in table floating headers when not floating

Tags: javascript, jquery

Link hover css not working in table header links only when the floatable headers are not floating or fully covering the original headers https://jsfiddle.net/jwLob72j/ (or without shadow)(please scroll-down a bit then scroll-up to remove shadow)

jquery makes the copy of headers to make floatable so the link hover css is also working but why only not working when floating headers fully covers the original headers, where is the problem that can be fixed?

```js
/*
     * jQuery throttle / debounce - v1.1 - 3/7/2010
     * http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/
     * 
     * Copyright (c) 2010 "Cowboy" Ben Alman
     * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
     * http://benalman.com/about/license/
     */
(function(b,c){var $=b.jQuery||b.Cowboy||(b.Cowboy={}),a;$.throttle=a=function(e,f,j,i){var h,d=0;if(typeof f!=="boolean"){i=j;j=f;f=c}function g(){var o=this,m=+new Date()-d,n=arguments;function l(){d=+new Date();j.apply(o,n)}function k(){h=c}if(i&&!h){l()}h&&clearTimeout(h);if(i===c&&m>e){l()}else{if(f!==true){h=setTimeout(i?k:l,i===c?e-m:e)}}}if($.guid){g.guid=j.guid=j.guid||$.guid++}return g};$.debounce=function(d,e,f){return f===c?a(d,e,false):a(d,f,e!==false)}})(this);









$(function(){
  $('table').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('thead').length > 0 && $(this).find('th').length > 0) {
      // Clone <thead>
      var $w    = $(window),
          $t    = $(this),
          $thead = $t.find('thead').clone(),
          $col   = $t.find('thead, tbody').clone();

      // Add class, remove margins, reset width and wrap table
      $t
      .addClass('sticky-enabled')
      .css({
        margin: 0,
        width: '100%'
      }).wrap('<div class="sticky-wrap" />');

      if($t.hasClass('overflow-y')) $t.removeClass('overflow-y').parent().addClass('overflow-y');

      // Create new sticky table head (basic)
      $t.after('<table class="sticky-thead" />');

      // If <tbody> contains <th>, then we create sticky column and intersect (advanced)
      if($t.find('tbody th').length > 0) {
        $t.after('<table class="sticky-col" /><table class="sticky-intersect" />');
      }

      // Create shorthand for things
      var $stickyHead  = $(this).siblings('.sticky-thead'),
          $stickyCol   = $(this).siblings('.sticky-col'),
          $stickyInsct = $(this).siblings('.sticky-intersect'),
          $stickyWrap  = $(this).parent('.sticky-wrap');

      $stickyHead.append($thead);

      $stickyCol
      .append($col)
      .find('thead th:gt(0)').remove()
      .end()
      .find('tbody td').remove();

      $stickyInsct.html('<thead><tr><th>'+$t.find('thead th:first-child').html()+'</th></tr></thead>');

      // Set widths
      var setWidths = function () {
        $t
        .find('thead th').each(function (i) {
          $stickyHead.find('th').eq(i).width($(this).width());
        })
        .end()
        .find('tr').each(function (i) {
          $stickyCol.find('tr').eq(i).height($(this).height());
        });

        // Set width of sticky table head
        $stickyHead.width($t.width());

        // Set width of sticky table col
        $stickyCol.find('th').add($stickyInsct.find('th')).width($t.find('thead th').width())
      },
          repositionStickyHead = function () {
            // Return value of calculated allowance
            var allowance = calcAllowance();

            // Check if wrapper parent is overflowing along the y-axis
            if($t.height() > $stickyWrap.height()) {
              // If it is overflowing (advanced layout)
              // Position sticky header based on wrapper scrollTop()
              if($stickyWrap.scrollTop() > 0) {
                // When top of wrapping parent is out of view
                $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                  opacity: 1,
                  top: $stickyWrap.scrollTop()
                });
              } else {
                // When top of wrapping parent is in view
                $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                  opacity: 0,
                  top: 0
                });
              }
            } else {
              // If it is not overflowing (basic layout)
              // Position sticky header based on viewport scrollTop
              if($w.scrollTop() > $t.offset().top && $w.scrollTop() < $t.offset().top + $t.outerHeight() - allowance) {
                // When top of viewport is in the table itself
                $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                  opacity: 1,
                  top: $w.scrollTop() - $t.offset().top
                });
              } else {
                // When top of viewport is above or below table
                $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                  opacity: 0,
                  top: 0
                });
              }
            }
          },
          repositionStickyCol = function () {
            if($stickyWrap.scrollLeft() > 0) {
              // When left of wrapping parent is out of view
              $stickyCol.add($stickyInsct).css({
                opacity: 1,
                left: $stickyWrap.scrollLeft()
              });
            } else {
              // When left of wrapping parent is in view
              $stickyCol
              .css({ opacity: 0 })
              .add($stickyInsct).css({ left: 0 });
            }
          },
          calcAllowance = function () {
            var a = 0;
            // Calculate allowance
            $t.find('tbody tr:lt(3)').each(function () {
              a += $(this).height();
            });

            // Set fail safe limit (last three row might be too tall)
            // Set arbitrary limit at 0.25 of viewport height, or you can use an arbitrary pixel value
            if(a > $w.height()*0.25) {
              a = $w.height()*0.25;
            }

            // Add the height of sticky header
            a += $stickyHead.height();
            return a;
          };

      setWidths();

      $t.parent('.sticky-wrap').scroll($.throttle(15, function() {
        repositionStickyHead();
        repositionStickyCol();
      }));

      $w
      .load(setWidths)
      .resize($.debounce(250, function () {
        setWidths();
        repositionStickyHead();
        repositionStickyCol();
      }))
      .scroll($.throttle(15, repositionStickyHead));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body{ margin:0; font-size:17px; color:#333; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; line-height:1.8em; background:#fff; -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale; }
a{ color:#333; }

table{ border-spacing:0; white-space:nowrap; cursor:default; line-height:1.4em; }
table thead th{ border:1px solid #ccc; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; background:#339966; color:#eee; padding:16px 8px; font-weight:normal; -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; -webkit-touch-callout:none; -khtml-user-select:none; }
table thead th a{ color:#fff; }
table thead th a:hover{ color:red; }
table tbody th{ border:1px solid #fff; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; background:#ddd; color:#222; padding:16px 8px; font-weight:normal; -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; -webkit-touch-callout:none; -khtml-user-select:none; }
table tbody th a{ color:#222; }
table tbody th a:hover{ color:red; }
table td{ padding:8px; border:1px solid #ccc; }
table > thead > tr > th{ vertical-align:top; }

.sticky-wrap{ position:relative; overflow-x:auto; margin:80px 1% 90px; }
.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead, .sticky-wrap .sticky-col, .sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect{ position:absolute; top:0; }
.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect{ opacity:1; z-index:10; display:none; }
.sticky-wrap td, .sticky-wrap th{ box-sizing:border-box; }

.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead{ transition:all 0.35s 0.1s ease-in-out; -o-transition:all 0.35s 0.1s ease-in-out; -moz-transition:all 0.35s 0.1s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition:all 0.35s 0.1s ease-in-out; box-shadow:0em 1em 1em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.7); -moz-box-shadow:0em 1em 1em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.7); -webkit-box-shadow:0em 1em 1em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.7); }

.sticky-wrap .sticky-col { transition:all 0.125s 0.1s ease-in-out; -o-transition:all 0.125s 0.1s ease-in-out; -moz-transition:all 0.125s 0.1s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition:all 0.125s 0.1s ease-in-out; box-shadow:1em 0em 1em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.7); -moz-box-shadow:1em 0em 1em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.7); -webkit-box-shadow:1em 0em 1em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.7); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
      <th><a href="https://google.com/">Google</a></th>
      <th><a href="https://yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a></th>
      <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
      <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
      <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
      <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
      <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
      <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
      <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th><a href="https://bing.com/">Bing</a></th>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><a href="https://aol.com/">AOL</a></th>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>CCC CCC CCC CCC</th>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>DDD DDD DDD DDD</th>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>AAA AAA AAA AAA</th>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>BBB BBB BBB BBB</th>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>CCC CCC CCC CCC</th>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>DDD DDD DDD DDD</th>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>AAA AAA AAA AAA</th>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>BBB BBB BBB BBB</th>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>CCC CCC CCC CCC</th>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>DDD DDD DDD DDD</th>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>AAA AAA AAA AAA</th>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>BBB BBB BBB BBB</th>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>CCC CCC CCC CCC</th>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>DDD DDD DDD DDD</th>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>AAA AAA AAA AAA</th>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>BBB BBB BBB BBB</th>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>CCC CCC CCC CCC</th>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>DDD DDD DDD DDD</th>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>AAA AAA AAA AAA</th>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>BBB BBB BBB BBB</th>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>CCC CCC CCC CCC</th>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>DDD DDD DDD DDD</th>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>AAA AAA AAA AAA</th>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
      <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>BBB BBB BBB BBB</th>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
      <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>CCC CCC CCC CCC</th>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
      <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>DDD DDD DDD DDD</th>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
      <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? everything seems to work here.

Comment: @AniMenon Scrolldown then scroll up to top, css hover no more works

Comment: @A.Wolff I just checked that on Chrome 49, it works. The above snippet is working.

Comment: @AniMenon It doesn't on chrome 50/win7

Comment: The thing is that sticky header (once displayed) is overlapping main table header, getting opacity 0, so CSS pseudo class `:hover` cannot work here. To hide it, this plugin shouldn't used opacity but display or at least add `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: @A.Wolff what can i do to make behaviour normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing...

```
// When top of viewport is above or below table
$stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
    opacity: 0,
    top: 0
});
```

to this....

```
// When top of viewport is above or below table
$stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
     opacity: 1,
    top: 0
});
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding, this seems to give the desired results.

Comment: can i also use `// When top of wrapping parent is in view
       $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
        opacity: 0,
        top: 0
       }); ` after changing opacity:1

Comment: and `// When left of wrapping parent is in view
      $stickyCol
      .css({ opacity: 0 })` after changing opacity:1

Comment: @BlackFire, // When top of wrapping parent is in view $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({ opacity: 1, top: 0 }); is needed for link hover down the left side. But I'm not sure about your 2nd question

Answer (score 1):

> [look this on codepen](http://codepen.io/Charlene/pen/bpZQgw)
>      change opacity = 0 to zIndex = -1, when scrolling to top, the thead element was cover by the cloned thead, it makes the original thead was behind the cloned one, leading to the hover effect is not working. Just change the zIndex of cloned thead will solve this problem.

```js
/**
 * Created by Charlene on 2016/5/11.
 */
/*
 * jQuery throttle / debounce - v1.1 - 3/7/2010
 * http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010 "Cowboy" Ben Alman
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * http://benalman.com/about/license/
 */
(function(b,c){var $=b.jQuery||b.Cowboy||(b.Cowboy={}),a;$.throttle=a=function(e,f,j,i){var h,d=0;if(typeof f!=="boolean"){i=j;j=f;f=c}function g(){var o=this,m=+new Date()-d,n=arguments;function l(){d=+new Date();j.apply(o,n)}function k(){h=c}if(i&&!h){l()}h&&clearTimeout(h);if(i===c&&m>e){l()}else{if(f!==true){h=setTimeout(i?k:l,i===c?e-m:e)}}}if($.guid){g.guid=j.guid=j.guid||$.guid++}return g};$.debounce=function(d,e,f){return f===c?a(d,e,false):a(d,f,e!==false)}})(this);









$(function(){
    $('table').each(function() {
        if($(this).find('thead').length > 0 && $(this).find('th').length > 0) {
            // Clone <thead>
            var $w    = $(window),
                $t    = $(this),
                $thead = $t.find('thead').clone(),
                $col   = $t.find('thead, tbody').clone();

            // Add class, remove margins, reset width and wrap table
            $t
                .addClass('sticky-enabled')
                .css({
                    margin: 0,
                    width: '100%'
                }).wrap('<div class="sticky-wrap" />');

            if($t.hasClass('overflow-y')) $t.removeClass('overflow-y').parent().addClass('overflow-y');

            // Create new sticky table head (basic)
            $t.after('<table class="sticky-thead" />');

            // If <tbody> contains <th>, then we create sticky column and intersect (advanced)
            if($t.find('tbody th').length > 0) {
                $t.after('<table class="sticky-col" /><table class="sticky-intersect" />');
            }

            // Create shorthand for things
            var $stickyHead  = $(this).siblings('.sticky-thead'),
                $stickyCol   = $(this).siblings('.sticky-col'),
                $stickyInsct = $(this).siblings('.sticky-intersect'),
                $stickyWrap  = $(this).parent('.sticky-wrap');

            $stickyHead.append($thead);

            $stickyCol
                .append($col)
                .find('thead th:gt(0)').remove()
                .end()
                .find('tbody td').remove();

            $stickyInsct.html('<thead><tr><th>'+$t.find('thead th:first-child').html()+'</th></tr></thead>');

            // Set widths
            var setWidths = function () {
                    $t
                        .find('thead th').each(function (i) {
                            $stickyHead.find('th').eq(i).width($(this).width());
                        })
                        .end()
                        .find('tr').each(function (i) {
                        $stickyCol.find('tr').eq(i).height($(this).height());
                    });

                    // Set width of sticky table head
                    $stickyHead.width($t.width());

                    // Set width of sticky table col
                    $stickyCol.find('th').add($stickyInsct.find('th')).width($t.find('thead th').width())
                },
                repositionStickyHead = function () {
                    // Return value of calculated allowance
                    var allowance = calcAllowance();

                    // Check if wrapper parent is overflowing along the y-axis
                    if($t.height() > $stickyWrap.height()) {
                        // If it is overflowing (advanced layout)
                        // Position sticky header based on wrapper scrollTop()
                        if($stickyWrap.scrollTop() > 0) {
                            // When top of wrapping parent is out of view
                            $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                                //opacity: 1,
                                zIndex: 1,
                                top: $stickyWrap.scrollTop()
                            });
                        } else {
                            // When top of wrapping parent is in view
                            $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                                //opacity: 0,
                                zIndex: 0,
                                top: 0
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        // If it is not overflowing (basic layout)
                        // Position sticky header based on viewport scrollTop
                        if($w.scrollTop() > $t.offset().top && $w.scrollTop() < $t.offset().top + $t.outerHeight() - allowance) {
                            // When top of viewport is in the table itself
                            $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                                //opacity: 1,
                                zIndex: 1,
                                top: $w.scrollTop() - $t.offset().top
                            });
                        } else {
                            // When top of viewport is above or below table
                            $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                                //opacity: 0,
                                zIndex: 0,
                                top: 0
                            });
                        }
                    }
                },
                repositionStickyCol = function () {
                    if($stickyWrap.scrollLeft() > 0) {
                        // When left of wrapping parent is out of view
                        $stickyCol.add($stickyInsct).css({
                            //opacity: 1,
                            zIndex: 1,
                            left: $stickyWrap.scrollLeft()
                        });
                    } else {
                        // When left of wrapping parent is in view
                        $stickyCol
                            //.css({ opacity: 0 })
                            .css({ zIndex: 0 })
                            .add($stickyInsct).css({ left: 0 });
                    }
                },
                calcAllowance = function () {
                    var a = 0;
                    // Calculate allowance
                    $t.find('tbody tr:lt(3)').each(function () {
                        a += $(this).height();
                    });

                    // Set fail safe limit (last three row might be too tall)
                    // Set arbitrary limit at 0.25 of viewport height, or you can use an arbitrary pixel value
                    if(a > $w.height()*0.25) {
                        a = $w.height()*0.25;
                    }

                    // Add the height of sticky header
                    a += $stickyHead.height();
                    return a;
                };

            setWidths();

            $t.parent('.sticky-wrap').scroll($.throttle(15, function() {
                repositionStickyHead();
                repositionStickyCol();
            }));

            $w
                .load(setWidths)
                .resize($.debounce(250, function () {
                    setWidths();
                    repositionStickyHead();
                    repositionStickyCol();
                }))
                .scroll($.throttle(15, repositionStickyHead));
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body{ margin:0; font-size:17px; color:#333; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; line-height:1.8em; background:#fff; -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale; }
a{ color:#333; }

table{ border-spacing:0; white-space:nowrap; cursor:default; line-height:1.4em; }
table thead th{ border:1px solid #ccc; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; background:#339966; color:#eee; padding:16px 8px; font-weight:normal; -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; -webkit-touch-callout:none; -khtml-user-select:none; }
table thead th a{ color:#fff; }
table thead th a:hover{ color:red; }
table tbody th{ border:1px solid #fff; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; background:#ddd; color:#222; padding:16px 8px; font-weight:normal; -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; -webkit-touch-callout:none; -khtml-user-select:none; }
table tbody th a{ color:#222; }
table tbody th a:hover{ color:red; }
table td{ padding:8px; border:1px solid #ccc; }
table > thead > tr > th{ vertical-align:top; }

.sticky-wrap{ position:relative; overflow-x:auto; margin:80px 1% 90px; }
.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead, .sticky-wrap .sticky-col, .sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect{ position:absolute; top:0; }
.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect{ opacity:1; z-index:10; display:none; }
.sticky-wrap td, .sticky-wrap th{ box-sizing:border-box; }

.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead{ transition:all 0.35s 0.1s ease-in-out; -o-transition:all 0.35s 0.1s ease-in-out; -moz-transition:all 0.35s 0.1s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition:all 0.35s 0.1s ease-in-out; box-shadow:0em 1em 1em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.7); -moz-box-shadow:0em 1em 1em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.7); -webkit-box-shadow:0em 1em 1em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.7); }

.sticky-wrap .sticky-col { transition:all 0.125s 0.1s ease-in-out; -o-transition:all 0.125s 0.1s ease-in-out; -moz-transition:all 0.125s 0.1s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition:all 0.125s 0.1s ease-in-out; box-shadow:1em 0em 1em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.7); -moz-box-shadow:1em 0em 1em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.7); -webkit-box-shadow:1em 0em 1em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.7); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="stackoverflow.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stackoverflow.css">
<table>
    <thead style="opacity: 1;">
    <tr>
        <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
        <th><a href="https://google.com/">Google</a></th>
        <th><a href="https://yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a></th>
        <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
        <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
        <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
        <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
        <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
        <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
        <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th><a href="https://bing.com/">Bing</a></th>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><a href="https://aol.com/">AOL</a></th>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>CCC CCC CCC CCC</th>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>DDD DDD DDD DDD</th>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>AAA AAA AAA AAA</th>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>BBB BBB BBB BBB</th>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>CCC CCC CCC CCC</th>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>DDD DDD DDD DDD</th>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>AAA AAA AAA AAA</th>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>BBB BBB BBB BBB</th>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>CCC CCC CCC CCC</th>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>DDD DDD DDD DDD</th>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>AAA AAA AAA AAA</th>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>BBB BBB BBB BBB</th>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>CCC CCC CCC CCC</th>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>DDD DDD DDD DDD</th>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>AAA AAA AAA AAA</th>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>BBB BBB BBB BBB</th>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>CCC CCC CCC CCC</th>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>DDD DDD DDD DDD</th>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>AAA AAA AAA AAA</th>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>BBB BBB BBB BBB</th>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>CCC CCC CCC CCC</th>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>DDD DDD DDD DDD</th>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>AAA AAA AAA AAA</th>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>BBB BBB BBB BBB</th>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>CCC CCC CCC CCC</th>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>DDD DDD DDD DDD</th>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when is tested your way i found that the top header goes under left header when i scroll table: right + up.

Comment: you are suggesting me to use zIndex = -1 , but i found that your are not using zIndex = -1 in your codepen

Comment: Hi @BlackFire ,i updated my [codepen](http://codepen.io/Charlene/pen/bpZQgw) . In your comment 1, you said that your present policy is column header first? Column header always on the top of row header?